# Need to understand Build log of Xcode 8.2.1 as its showing details with some strange log

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

As I have updated the latest version of `XCode` it's showing some new build log in `XCode` Build time log

**Look at below screenshot:**

[image]

**Log 1:**

> Showing All Messages
>
> sent 278 bytes  received 20 bytes  596.00 bytes/sec

**Log 2:**

> Showing All Messages
>
> total size is 19764  speedup is 66.32

I want to know what kind of data it's sending to and where?

As I am working with an enterprise app and it's very important to not send or leak any kind of data outside origination.

Any help or guide will be appreciated.

Comment: I tried performing few api calls with  latest xcode (8.2.1), I didn't receive any such logs. An Insight to code will help!

Comment: Well, its from cocoapods and not Xcode itself it seems, and I'm quite sure it was doing the same thing before you updated to Xcode 8.2.1. As for what is being sent, I'd assume that it maybe some statistics, but it's just me guessing. You may also try asking at cocoapods github https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods